# .htaccess Password protected website requires Password at every page reload on Ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, html5-audio

I use .htaccess to protect a website with a password.

If i use html5 audio elements on that website my Ipad requires the website password at each reload, although it's saved in the browser.

Only on Ipad. Not rooted, all original ios. 
Tested with Chrome and Safari on Ipad, always the same.

If there is no audio element on the page, it doesn't require the password.

This doesn't happen on an Android Tablet or Firefox in Windows.

What can i program to prevent the Ipad asking for the password?

I use the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826147/javascript-audio-play-on-click) from this website.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Audio</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function play(){
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.play();
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src="./207.wav"></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

The .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName name123
AuthUserFile /somepath/.htpasswd
require valid-user
SetEnv no-gzip
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: I guess you need to provide the .htaccess file for other the trouble-shoot?

Comment: Of course, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [very old problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3772253?tstart=0). Safari browser disables sending auth params when doing something *automatically* - [redirect with 301-302 http codes](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3274071) or loading media file. Looks like this is a sequrity issue - Safari doesn't allow access to a file, loaded *automatically*.

Let's check it with server logs (I've added an image to the page):

`GET /t/i.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200` images are loaded great.

`GET /t/207.wav HTTP/1.0" 401` audio is not loaded, prompt is shown.

So it is the audio file that forces auth prompt to show. There is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178507/mp4-in-safari-fails-with-htaccess-authentication), but is is not secure enough.

UPD. The following code shows 200-response for first access (`img` tag) to `207.wav` and 401 for the second (`audio` tag).

```
<img src="./207.wav" width=200><br>
<audio id="audio" src="./207.wav"></audio>

217.118.81.250 - ivan [11/Feb/2017:20:32:13 +0300] "GET /t/207.wav HTTP/1.0" 200 ... Safari/602.1"
217.118.81.250 - - [11/Feb/2017:20:32:15 +0300] "GET /t/207.wav HTTP/1.0" 401 ... Safari/602.1"
```

Comment: You mean ios in general? Because this problem also happens with Chrome on ios.

Comment: If you look at `User-agent`, you see something like `AppleWebKit/602.1.50 blabla Safari/602.1` *even if it is Chrome or Opera browser*. I'm not aware of internal architecture of browsers in iOs, but it looks like they use the same engine `AppleWebKit` as Safari does.

Comment: Apple do not allow any one to create there own Browser View you must use the Safari embedded browser in there apps so Chrome, Opera, Firefox all have to use the Embedded Safari in iOS

Comment: @MartinBarker Thanks for that input, would be worth reputation as well, but i can only give shukshin.ivan.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Thanks, completely true, also the workaround worked. As  it is only one simple wav file, i guess the security issues are negligible.